# Deploy a safe contract to Arbitrum using the same safe address

Tags: gnosis-safe

Basically following the video provided here, https://forum.safe.global/t/how-can-a-safe-hold-asset-on-multiple-chains/2242/5

Wanna confirm that the Arbitrum chain ID Safe uses is 42161(0xa4b1). Previously I can find that directly in the repo to check myself but I cannot seem to be able to find the blob

Comment: Looks right to me